# SQL Error in Docker

Tags: mysql, docker

My goal is to run some commands in my Dockerfile that will create an sql user and give him some privileges. So I do the following:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
...
RUN apt-get install -y apache2
RUN apt-get install -y mysql-server
RUN mysql -Bse "CREATE USER 'testuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'testpass';"
RUN mysql -Bse "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'testuser'@'localhost';"
```

This crashes at the first mysql command

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

However, if found through StackExchange that if I remove the sql commands from Dockerfile and login with docker exec in a running container, the following solution will work:

```
service apache2 stop
service mysql stop
service mysql start
service apache2 start
mysql -Bse "CREATE USER 'testuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'testpass';"
mysql -Bse "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'testuser'@'localhost';"
```

As I want all the commands to be in the Dockerfile, I tried the above `service stop/start` solution, but it will not work from Dockerfile, only after exec in an already running container. I suppose a different solution is required.

How can I automate these execution of these sql commands without having to run them manually with docker exec? Thank you

P.S. let me know if the question would be more suitable for another Stack Exchange site.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to the fact that every RUN command is running in a different layer. The solution was to add all related commands into a bash script init_db.sh file and execute it in the Dockerfile.

```
#!/bin/bash

service apache2 stop
service mysql stop
service mysql start
service apache2 start

mysql -Bse "CREATE USER 'testuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'testpass';"
mysql -Bse "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'testuser'@'localhost';"
```

```
ADD init_db.sh /tmp/init_db.sh
RUN /tmp/init_db.sh
```

source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25920029/setting-up-mysql-and-importing-dump-within-dockerfile